# PyQt5: Вывод линий с задержкой

Tags: pyqt5, время, таймер

Мне необходимо реализовать вывод с задержкой. Попробовал вот так

```
def draw(window):
    window.scene.addLine(10, 10, 300, 300, pen=window.pen)
    sleep(2)
    window.scene.addLine(59, 60, 200, 100, pen=window.pen)
    sleep(2)
    window.scene.addLine(100, 10, 500, 500, pen=window.pen)
    sleep(2)
    window.scene.addLine(10, 10, 440, 400, pen=window.pen)
```

Но работает не так, как хотелось бы. Программа просто останавливается на N секунд, а после выводит сразу все линии. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `Qt` таймером - `QTimer`

`from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QEventLoop`

```
loop = QEventLoop()
QTimer.singleShot(2000, loop.quit) # 2000 = 2 секунды
loop.exec()
```